# How to read names of all properties and its values from application.properties file in java spring boot app

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, application.properties

I want to read all the values and its key from application.properties file in Java spring boot application.

I can across this [article](https://www.codejava.net/frameworks/spring-boot/read-values-from-application-properties-file) which read values in multiple ways. The problem with this approach is every time you add a property, we need to update the code.

I want a dynamic way to read all keys and values. I do not want to make code changes once a property is added to application.properties file.

I tried something like this and did not got the desired result:

```
@Autowired
    private Environment environment;

    @GetMapping
    public Map<String, String> getAllProperties() {
        Map<String, String> properties = new HashMap<>();

        // Get all property names
        String[] propertyNames = environment.getProperty("spring.config.name", "application").split(",");
        for (String propertyName : propertyNames) {
            String propertyValue = environment.getProperty(propertyName);
            properties.put(propertyName, propertyValue != null ? propertyValue : "null");
        }

        return properties;
    }
```

I checked and application.properties file is located under `src/main/resources` & the file name is `application.properties`

Let me know if what I am trying to achieve is possible or not.

Comment: Can you say *why* you would want to do this?

Comment: I want to print all the properties. The idea is when I deploy in dev environment, system should read from application-dev.properties file . I want to just print all the values to check based on env variable, application is reading the right file.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to read all properties values from the source properties file in Spring-cloud-config client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38035340/how-to-read-all-properties-values-from-the-source-properties-file-in-spring-clou)

Answer (score 0):

your properties are in resources, writing to resources is a bad idea

Of course, you can write a separate method that will read from the properties file, but you will have problems when you build your project in war or jar

Create a hidden folder and put whatever you want there

Comment: Can you please explain what do you mean by `you will have problems when you build your project in war or jar`

Comment: your jar will grove or if you use url for property your path will different, change your resources in runtime it is bad practice

Comment: But saw your answer in comment, as I understand it, you don’t want to change the properties in real time, then you can read the properties by class louder or along the file path

Comment: Can you please provide more information/sample about `read the properties by class louder or along the file path`

Comment: URL resource = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("application-test_pg.properties");
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.load(resource.openStream());
properties.forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println(k + " | " + v));

Comment: Be aware that `load` does not close the stream. That code can be shortened too

Answer (score 0):

Try with the following code:

```java
PropertySource<?> propertySource =
    ((AbstractEnvironment) environment)
        .getPropertySources().stream()
            .filter(i -> i instanceof OriginTrackedMapPropertySource)
            .filter(i -> i.getName().contains("application.properties"))
            .findFirst()
            .orElseThrow();
Map<String, String> properties = (Map<String, String>) propertySource.getSource();
```

`Environment` bean contains all property sources, but it needs to be cast to `AbstractEnvironment` to access property sources directly. Then those should be filtered to remain only `OriginTrackedMapPropertySource`s.

Finally, filter property sources by name containing the file name. The reason why the `contains` is used is that the names of remaining property sources are in the following format:

> Config resource 'class path resource [application.properties]' via
> location 'optional:classpath:/'

Remember that those properties are the original values from the file, but can be overridden by, for example, profile-specific properties. In that case, `environment.getProperty(propertyName)` would return a different value than one read from the code above.

For reference: [Access all Environment properties as a Map or Properties object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23506471/access-all-environment-properties-as-a-map-or-properties-object)